# Android Layout Problem

Tags: android, layout

I need some help with layout. I have a horizontal view with buttons, another linear layout with buttons below, then listview and then AdView (AdMob) at the bottom. My problem is that the bottom AdView overlays the listview and I can't get it right. See my code attached. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.example"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/Lay1"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <HorizontalScrollView 
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" 
                android:layout_height="60px">
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_1" 
                    style="@style/RSSButtonText"   
                    android:background="@layout/rssbuttonshape"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_2" 
                    style="@style/RSSButtonText"   
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_3" 
                    style="@style/RSSButtonText"   
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_4" 
                    style="@style/RSSButtonText"   
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_5" 
                    style="@style/RSSButtonText"   
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_6" 
                    style="@style/RSSButtonText"   
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_7" 
                    style="@style/RSSButtonText"   
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_11" 
                android:text="Button11"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2">
            </Button>   
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_12" 
            android:text="Button12"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2">
            </Button>   
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_13" 
                android:text="Button13"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2">
            </Button>   
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_14" 
            android:text="Button14"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no"
                android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2">
            </Button>   
        </LinearLayout>   
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
            </ListView>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/Lay1">
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.google.example"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
         />
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/Lay1" android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_above="@+id/adview">
        <HorizontalScrollView android:scrollbars="none"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:layout_height="60px">
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_1" style="@style/RSSButtonText"
                    android:background="@layout/rssbuttonshape" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_2" style="@style/RSSButtonText"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_3" style="@style/RSSButtonText"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_4" style="@style/RSSButtonText"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_5" style="@style/RSSButtonText"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_6" style="@style/RSSButtonText"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
                <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_7" style="@style/RSSButtonText"
                    android:background="@android:color/transparent" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_11" android:text="Button11"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no" android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_12" android:text="Button12"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no" android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_13" android:text="Button13"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no" android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2" />
            <Button android:id="@+id/SCHButton_14" android:text="Button14"
                android:background="@drawable/button_no" android:layout_width="120px"
                style="@style/ButtonText2" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#FFFFFF" android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
                android:drawSelectorOnTop="false" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Nope. Unfortunately now the listview overlaps the bottom adView. Any other ideas?

Comment: using the above layout, try setting the height of the admob linearlayout.  It may be that because it is "wrap_content" but it doesn't know the size until the admob until after its been drawn.  just try it at something like android:layout_height="50dp"

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"       
        android:layout_below="@+id/Lay1">
    </LinearLayout>
```